# Swift generic collection of Element cannot convert to collection of Any

Tags: swift, generics, collections, typing

I'm facing a problem I don't understand.
In my project, I want to make a collection of elements with some customised methods (like an update from a server). But when I try to group all these collections in an array, I get an error: "Cannot convert value of type `MyCollection<someElement>` to expected argument type `MyCollection<Any>`"

What I don't understand is that the same code with Array is working... Array isn't a collection?

```swift
// My collection which would contain an update method
class MyCollection<Element> {
    var object:Element? = nil
}

let x = MyCollection<Int>()
var list = [MyCollection<Any>]()
list.append(x) //Cannot convert value of type 'MyCollection<In>' to expected argument type 'MyCollection<Any>'

let a = Array<Int>()
var lista = [Array<Any>]()
lista.append(a) //Doesn't get error at all...
```

I know I can do this with an array of the specific type but by grouping all of MyCollection in an array, I wish to use a code like :

```swift
func update() {
    for e in list { // array of MyCollection<Any>
        e.update()
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to convert from `SomeType<Subtype>` to `SomeType<Supertype>` is called covariance. In Swift, [`Array<T>` is covariant on `T` by "compiler magic", and you can't do the same for your own types](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-are-array-and-value-covariant/36064).

> The type checker hardcodes conversions from Array to Array if there is a conversion from T to U. Similar rules exist for Optional and Dictionary. There's no mechanism for doing this with your own types.

Your own generic types are always invariant, meaning that there is never a conversion between `SomeType<T>` to `SomeType<U>`, as long as `T` and `U` are different types.

Let's imagine what would happen if the conversion on `MyCollection` were allowed. You could do:

```
let myCollectionInt = MyCollection<Int>()
let myCollectionAny: MyCollection<Any> = myCollectionInt // suppose you can do this
myCollectionAny.object = "string" // myCollectionAny.object is of type Any?, so this should be ok
```

We've set `myCollectionAny.object` to "string", but `MyCollection` is a reference type, so `myCollectionInt.object` should also be "string". But `myCollectionInt.object` is an `Int?`!

Of course this type-unsafety is also a problem with arrays, but the language designers have decided that casting arrays is a common enough thing to do, that disallowing it would do more hard than good.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This concept, to me, seems to go very deep in swift basement and I'm not sure my programming skill is high enough to understand the ins and outs of all of this. This is not the first time I'm in troubles with generic struct/class type checker... I will look for a different way to do what I need. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @TheSnowFox Forst Array it is not a class it is a struct. Second your class does not ccnform to collection.  If you had implement a proper generic type that conform to collection you would get the same behaviour as the array.

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm pretty sure the language gives special treatment only to arrays, not to "any `Collection` struct". I tried with `CollectionOfOne`, for example, and it doesn't compile as expected. `let a = CollectionOfOne(""); let b: CollectionOfOne<Any> = a`

Comment: @Sweeper Seems to me that the issue above is that you are trying to assign a single object to a collection. https://gist.github.com/leodabus/aefeb8690377ee6ddccf075fffaeb036

Comment: @LeoDabus OP has an array of `MyCollection<Any>`s, called `list`, and OP is trying to add a `MyCollection<Int>` to that array, so a conversion from `MyCollection<Int>` to `MyCollection<Any>` is needed. I explained why you can never do that implicitly with your own types.

Comment: MyCollection is very misleading as it is not a collection. It is just a generic structure. I am not arguing about your post. I am just saying that if implemented correctly this would work exactly the same as an array.

Comment: @LeoDabus I think what I'm confused about is, what do you mean by "work exactly the same as an array"? I still can't implicitly convert `MyCollection<Int>` to `MyCollection<Any>`, can I?

Comment: @Sweeper I see what you mean. No you can't.

Comment: @Sweeper What I meant was `let x = MyCollection<Int>()`
`var list = MyCollection<Any>()`
`list.append(x)`  does work

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah, I knew there was some misunderstanding there.

Comment: @Sweeper https://gist.github.com/leodabus/aefeb8690377ee6ddccf075fffaeb036